# Redirect user to page depending on IP address not working

Tags: php, if-statement, ip-address

The IP address of the computer that I am using is the one specified in $ip. The problem is that when $userip **!=** $ip, the message is displayed, which it should not. The first version of the if statement is ideally  how I want the page to work. Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks in advance.

***Note: The purpose of the if statement is to ensure that the users access the site from a particular computer. For example, employees can only access the site from their work station computer (not from PCs). If they are not at their work station computer, then the message is displayed.***

***Note: I got the $ip from running an "ipconfig /a"ll command.***

***Note: I am currently testing this with one IP address and I will eventually test with multiple ones.***

```
$userip = ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
$ip = '172.34.56.202';

if ($userip != $ip) {
    echo "<h3>" . "ACCESS DENIED. Your IP address is not in the list of allowed IPs" . "</h3>";
} else{
    $URL="http://www.yahoo.com";
    header ("Location: $URL");
}
?>
```

**I also tried to change around the operations of the if statement in this version, but it still doesn't work..the error message is still displayed instead of directing the user to a different page:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$userip = ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
$ip = '172.34.56.202';

if ($userip == $ip) {
    $URL="http://wt-ws.delta.lasalle.edu/tempProject/timeSheetProject/TimeSheet.php";
    header ("Location: $URL");

} else{
    echo "<h3>" . "ACCESS DENIED. Your IP address is not in the list of allowed IPs" . "</h3>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to `echo $userip;`?

Comment: You shouldn't ban users because of their IPs. Many user don't use their real IP. The IP address might also change (for instance mine changes very night and I get someone else's). Keep also in mind that it is possible to guess the link or get it somehow. You should rather add a proper authorization system where the link points to.

Comment: The usual method for this is through `.htaccess` But I suppose you have a specific reason for not using that mechanism (more powerful, general, robust...)

Comment: @Matt3o12 I probably should have mentioned this in my post..the purpose of the if statement is to ensure that the users accesses the site from a particular computer. For example, employees can only access the site from their work station computer (not from PCs). If they are not at their work station computer, then the message is displayed. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @user3666355, well that's different than. Keep also in mind that the employees might access the server with their local IP address This IP is different from the global IP address. [Here](http://lifehacker.com/5833108/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address) is a nice article about it by lifehackers. It might also be helpful to use a regular expression to allow multiple workstations on the same network to have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the above code and it works just fine on my end for the page I created.

The only thing I would suggest is doing

```
echo($userip);
```

To see what the value is for `$userip`. As if you are doing this on a test box installed on your machine your IP very well could be 127.0.0.1 , as you are viewing the file local.

To your updated question
When you use `ipconfig /a` this gives you the IP address assigned to your machine. Most networks use a subnet mask and a private IP Address. For example if you use `ipconfig /a` and get an IP address in the following ranges it is a private non routable IP address.

```
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 - Class A
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 - Class B
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 - Class C
```

To find your public IP Address you can do this a couple of ways:

- [You can google what is my ip?](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip)
- [www.ipchicken.com](http://www.ipchicken.com/)
- [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/)

Comment: I added the line just like you suggested. However, the page displayed an IP that was different from the $ip that I got from running an ipconfig /all. So was both the IPs in your code and the IP from your echo the same? Should I change my IP to the one dispalyed on the page? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's more likely your private IP and not your public IP. To get your public IP goto a site like ipchicken.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the identical comparison operators such as **!==** or **===** ?